# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un corte de una fecha a otra en c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, stored-procedure

Buenas tardes tengo una duda de como puedo realizar un corte, tengo un WinForms como en la imagen y cree un store procedure pero no funciona, mi código del WinForm es el siguiente, Necesito sacar un corte en un período de fecha para determinar el importe a pagar por cursos, así como determinar el costo máximo, costo mínimo y costo promedio.

```
 public xENC150010()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = Corte(DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text), DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker2.Text));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        decimal Total = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Total += Convert.ToDecimal(row["importe"]);
        }
        textBox1.Text = Total.ToString();
    }

    private void xENC150010_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blblForma.Caption = this.Name;
    }
    public DataTable Corte(DateTime Fecha1, DateTime Fecha2)
    {

        string sql = "filtro";

        SqlConnection cn = newSqlConnection(NASA.PROCNASA.GLOBAL.CONFIG.SystemConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha1", Fecha1);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha2", Fecha2);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cn.Open();

        da.Fill(dt);

        cn.Close();

        return dt;

    }
```

y mi store procedure es el siguiente:

```
 @FechaInicio DATE,
    @FechaFin DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        SUM(r.importe) AS ImporteTotal,
        MAX(c.costo) AS CostoMaximo,
        MIN(c.costo) AS CostoMinimo,
        AVG(c.costo) AS CostoPromedio
    FROM
        dbo.CursosENC c
        INNER JOIN dbo.RegistrosENC r ON c.idCurso = r.idCurso
    WHERE
        r.fechaInscr BETWEEN @FechaInicio AND @FechaFin
END
```

Tomando en cuenta que el importe se encuentra en la tabla dbo.RegistrosENC.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si lo que no te funciona es el store puede ser porque el formato de fecha que pasas desde c# no es el mismo que requiere sql

Comment: En c# el campo fechaInscr lo tengo declarado como Datetime

Comment: Seguramente esto te pueda ayudar: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121309/11539923)

Answer (score 0):

Los parametros que estas mandando en tu código no corresponden con los definidos en al procedimiento almacenado:

Cambia esto:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha1", Fecha1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha2", Fecha2);
```

Por esto:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaInicio ", Fecha1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaFin", Fecha2);
```

Adicional, puede haber un tema con la hora que incluyen las variables del tipo DateTime, esto hará que varien los resultados de la consulta, para solucionarlo puedes revisar el post de Lenadro Tuttini, donde lo explica muy bien y sugiere dos alternativas:

[Filtrar rango de fechas](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/09/adonet-filtrar-rango-de-fechas.html)